# Migrate from OrientDB to AWS Neptune

Tags: orientdb, amazon-neptune

I need to migrate a database from OrientDB to Neptune. I have an exported JSON file from Orient that contains the schema (classes) and the records - I now need to import this into Neptune. However, it seems that to import data into Neptune there must be a csv file containing all the vertex's and another file containing all the edges.

Are there any existing tools to help with this migration and converting to the required files/format?

Comment: Are you able to export anything other than JSON? If you can export GraphML there is an open source tool that can turn that into the appropriate CSV files.

Comment: @KelvinLawrence I've just seen that it might be possible using Gremlin to export GraphML (XML). Do you have a link to that tool?

Comment: I'll write up a quick answer with a link to the tool

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to export the data as GraphML then you can use the [GraphML2CSV](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-neptune-tools/blob/master/graphml2csv/README.md) tool. It will create a CSV file for the nodes and another for the edges with the appropriate header rows.

Keep in mind that GraphML is a lossy format (it cannot describe complex Java types the way GraphSON can) but you would not be able to import those into Neptune either.